# Magento - slow homepage

Tags: performance, magento, caching, loading

Have problem with loading homepage of my site. PHP execution time is about `14sec` !!! Other pages like categories have 1,5sec to execution. Cache are enabled also I clean DB with no results.

Comment: There is no clear programming questions here. There is a site for [magento.se] questions, but I suggest reading their [help page](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs over on magento.stackexchange. CMS isn't cached, you have a bloated front page with a lot of database calls, or you have a server that's inadequate to serve out the CMS content. A Full Page Cache (FPC) that caches CMS pages will help somewhat mask the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The cache being enabled doesn't help if the blocks you have on your homepage aren't setup to be cached. If you have any custom blocks generating content on your homepage you should set the cache lifetime and override the getCacheKeyInfo. Especially if these blocks are doing large DB queries involving joins across many EAV tables. Obviously there's not much anyone can do with the limited information you've given, but start by looking at your homepage layout XML to see which blocks are being used, and investigate whether they are being cached.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install FPC.
2. Pre-warm Cache.
3. Make sure if any listing then flat tables are used.
4. No block level code in .phtml

In short you need to know how to optimise magenta for performance

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem with Full Page Cache Thanks!